# Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication

I cannot connect at all using forms authentication because i get the following message:

```
Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired. 
Event time: 8/31/2010 3:35:58 PM 
Event time (UTC): 8/31/2010 12:35:58 PM 
Event ID: b566569a3ac244928af9585691f997ef 
Event sequence: 12 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50202
```

Relevant web.config sections:

```
    <machineKey validationKey="DBD8250ABB1B0D07E5F490C0F0D8D7DA783597A0E232177C" decryptionKey="428C3A22DE12A294CAAFBEC7DA6919E80F7D11319D5DB23A" validation="SHA1" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/customlogin.aspx" path="/" protection="All" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Additional details: this is not a farm, but a single server machine.
The issue is reproduced every time I try to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it just needed an iisreset.